# Display bullet as password character in visual c++

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I can't seem to display a bullet as the password character in a Visual C++ forms app. I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Pro.

I made a textbox and changed the PasswordChar property to "\u2022" (the unicode for the bullet). It shows up as a bullet in the forms designer property box, but not in the textbox when the app is running. I just get those "missing character" empty box characters. I have tried multiple different fonts, all of which support this character according to [www.fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/fontsupport.htm)

What am I doing wrong? Obviously I could use an asterisk or some other character but this will bug me unless I know why it's not working... :)

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution, but having become increasingly frustrated with Visual C++, I restarted in C# and everything works tickity-boo. Must be a bug in VS2008 I guess.